# Why does this function call work even though I inverted two parameters?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linker

I'm working on a variation of the Nelder-Mead algorithm from *Numerical Recipes*, that would allow the user to specify a maximum number of target function calls to be made.

From my main routine, here is how I call the `amoeba()` function that implements the Nelder-Mead algorithm:

```
amoeba(p,y,params->ndim,params->tol,params->nmax,internal_funk,&nfunc);
```

But here is how it got implemented:

```
void amoeba(float **p, float y[], int ndim, unsigned nmax, float ftol, float (*funk)(float []), int *nfunk) {
....
}
```

Notice that I inverted the `nmax` and the `ftol` arguments in my function call.

**Astonishingly, `amoeba()` still works**. Stepping through it in a debugger confirms that the right values were assigned to `nmax` and `ftol`.

My main routine `#include`d a header file that defines the signature of the `amoeba()` routine, and compiling the main routine yielded no errors. However, the `amoeaba()` source file did **not** include that header (a mistake of mine), and so the compiler did not generate any errors either.

So how come my linked program still functions as it should, even though the arguments are not given in the right order?

**UPDATE**

@Binyamin Sharet, I'm showing here the assembly right before the call to `amoeba` and in `amoeba`. Does it support your hypothesis?

[image: Before call to <code>amoeba</code>]

[image: Inside <code>amoeba</code>]

**UPDATE 2**

@Binyamin Sharet sure, here it is:

[image]

Comment: They're unique values and still showing the correct values inside the function?

Comment: first of all, enable warnings...

Comment: @DanF Yes. Not even the same type. nmax is 1000, ftol is about 5e-5. @yi_H, here are the warnings I've enabled: `-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wconversion`

Comment: Looking at your code, yes, it looks just like that. The instruction `movss` is used for moving floating point numbers (introduced in SSE). Seems like I was off a bit, as it moves the number to a special register, and not the coprocessor stack, but it's the same idea...

Comment: And BTW, the first disassembly you posted was just fine, I misread it, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is probably, because the floating points parameters are not passed on the stack, but on the co-processor stack, so the order of those two didn't matter.

For example, the function expects this order of arguments:

```
   |         p              |                             |
   |         y              |                             |
   |         ndim           |                             |
   |         nmax           |                             |
   |         funk           |                             |
   |         nfunk          |          ftol               |
   +------------------------+-----------------------------+
   |        stack           |        coprocessor stack    |
```

It didn't matter if you switch `nmax` and `ftol`, because the order on the stacks would be the same, and when the `amoeba` tries to read them, it doesn't get confused for the same reason.

---

**Edit**

Reading the disassembly shows that I was off a bit, but that because of [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions), the instruction used for passing the float variable is [`movss`](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/vtune/doc/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc203.htm), which you can see in both assemblt listing you added, one time to `xmm0` register (in the caller), and one time from `xmm0` (in the callee). so you can replace the words **coprocessor-stack** with **xmm registers** and that's your situation.

Comment: needless to say, but this is working only by chance: most probably, on a different platform, it wouldn't work

Comment: I absolutely agree, I wanted to wrote "you got lucky" but then deleted it because I didn't think it's so lucky. probably chance is the correct word for that.

Comment: Wellll.... I spotted this in our unit tests, but the real code runs on an embedded platform that doesn't have hardware support for floating point... woops ;-)